# How to add relationships and custom fields to the email module in SugarCRM 7.2?

Tags: module, relationship, sugarcrm

In SugarCRM --> Admin --> Studio, all modules are listed that can be edited. The core module of "Emails" is not one of them. How can I add my custom relationships/fields to this table? The one relationship in particular that I am looking to make is contact_has_email. It will simply designate which emails are associated with which contact.

Can this be done with code in some way? Can it be done in Studio or the GUI somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add empty studio.php file under modules/Emails/metadata/

And go to studio, Emails module will there , enjoy

Comment: Adding the file only was not enough, I had to run 'Quick Repair and Rebuild' under 'Repair' to make it appear.